# Were political parties in the U.S during 1918 as polarized generally as they are now?

Tags: united-states

There was a pandemic in 1918, and there is one now as well, but were political parties back then as polarized generally as they are now in the United States.

Comment: Polarized generally or specifically about the handling of the pandemic?

Comment: This is a subjective question; H:SE question should have the possibility of [authoritative answers](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401).  How do you measure polarization?  How polarized were the political parties in 1918?

Comment: polarized generally

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Comment: You probably want to edit your comment "polarized generally" back into the question; I'm not sure where it fits.

Comment: You should also specify what political parties you are asking about (presumably, Democratic party and GOP). I also do not understand what "generally" means. Do you mean "disagreed on almost all issues"? Voted almost entirely along party lines? Etc. Lastly: As requires by HSE, please indicate what preliminary research you have done to answer your question.

Comment: The current polarization is extremely recent.   It's very much a product of the [last two decades](https://www.pewresearch.org/politics/interactives/political-polarization-1994-2017/)

Answer (score 3):

1918 was during the [Fourth Party System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Party_System) that was in effect from 1896 to 1928. Under this system, the Republican party was principally a party of business interests and skilled workers, along with what few African-Americans were allowed to vote, while the Democratic party was a coalition of white supremacists (particularly in the South), unskilled workers, and immigrants. The Republicans usually had the upper hand, with only one Democrat elected POTUS during this period.

[image]
<sup>Political map of the 4th Party system. The darker the shade, the more likely the state was to vote for that party's candidate.</sup>

With these coalitions there were wings in both parties in support and in opposition to many national issues. The big issues that starkly separated them was tariffs (protectionism) and the handling of the monetary system. But if those are not issues that get you going like it did people at that time, then both parties would look rather diverse. Both parties had what we'd today call "conservatives" (Republican business interests, Democratic White Supremacists) and "liberals" (Republican progressives, Democratic Labor and Immigrant interests).

However, if those (now rather arcane-looking) macroeconomic issues were your primary political animation, the parties would look quite divided.

The subsequent [Fifth ("New Deal") System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Party_System) saw black voters switch en-masse to the Democrats, and the White Supremacists start to drift away from them. With [the Sixth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Party_System) (arguably the current system) the White Supremacist wing fully switched parties, while the [Progressive Republicans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockefeller_Republican) switched the other way, and that is how we got to the current situation where one party is a coalition of pretty much all the nation's "conservative" interests, while the other has everyone else.

Comment: I left off any mention of the 1918 Pandemic, because I'm unaware of any particularly uniform partisan schism over it at the time. The incumbent POTUS lost the next election, but that was more likely due to the (admittedly likely pandemic-caused) recession than due to his handling of the pandemic.

Comment: Wilson wasn't nominated in 1920, and a third term would have been unprecedented.   (Not to mention his health issues.)

Comment: I would add that the key issue at the time was the US entry into the first world war, which had broad bipartisan (Dems and GOP) support.

Comment: There were other issues, such as voting rights for women and Prohibition, that were probably quiite polarizing at the time.

Comment: @jamesqf - Prohibition had support and opposition from wings of both parties. I was only listing the issues that the two parties were unified (within themselves) on. There's a whole section on Prohibition behind the 4th Party System link in the answer, if you're interested in reading more about it.